# How to Create an XML object in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, object

I want to pass an XML object from code behind file of an aspx to an class library.for that how can i create a XML Object. 
please its urgent.

Answer (score 3):

.NET includes multiple XML APIs (XML Document—a typical DOM implementation, a streaming API, an XPath orientated API and LINQ to XML). So lots to chose from.

Without more detail impossible to say which is your best approach. I would suggest starting reading MSDN at ["XML Documents and Data"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bcctyt8.aspx).

Comment: I want to create an xml object it should not be an XMl file.

Comment: All of the four APIs allow XMl objects to be created (and loaded/saved to files/data streams). Without more details (e.g. do you want a specific type of object?) it is hard to suggest something more specific.

Answer (score 2):

Load an XML file from disk
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807.aspx

or some XML from a string

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx